# How to make a link not appear in discord.py responses?

Tags: python, discord.py

I need help with an problem I've had today with discord.py.

This is my current code with the problem

```
@client.command()
async def flip(ctx):
    sides = ['Heads',
             'Tails']
    await ctx.send(f"Flipped a coin! Got {random.choice(sides)}. \nhttps://imgur.com/FCkKlxF")
```

It comes out as: https://gyazo.com/644253f622d2267e8b3d7d0d8142fc42
However, I want it to not include this part: https://gyazo.com/016cb568b58a3fe7809f564b4a4e03ce

So long story short, I do not know how to remove the link without removing the image.
I hope someone can help

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend sending an [Embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed), you can add your image with `embed.set_image`

Something like

```
e = discord.Embed()
e.description = f"Flipped a coin! Got {random.choice(sides)}."
e.set_image("https://i.imgur.com/FCkKlxF.jpg")

await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

Should look something like

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This will help a lot in the future but I still would like to just remove the link. Please reply if it's possible to help.

Comment: You can't just make the link disappear, you either have to put it in an embed or upload it every time in a [discord.File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20file#discord.File)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to do a hyperlink or something like that. It is possible with embeds. Here is an example:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title='My Image Link',
                       url='https://imgur.com/FCkKlxF')
```